# How to insert white space in RichTextBox

Tags: windows-phone-7, richtextbox, whitespace

I am trying to make a WP7 app and I'm facing an issue on how to add a white space after a part of text. I know that this thing can be done in HTML by inserting a &nbsp char but in my RichTextBox this can't be done.
This is my code:

```
<RichTextBox>
  <Paragraph>
    <Run>This is a </Run>
    <Bold Foreground="Red">test</Bold>
  </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

I want the output to look like "This is a test" but the last whitespace is ignored so the output is "This is atest" .

Can you please help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have found what was the issue , in designer the output was the wrong one ("This is atest") but at run-time it's displayed ok.